# Inputenc error pgfplotsset

Tags: pgfplots, errors, input-encodings

When I try to compile my code throw me an error between inputenc and pgfplots.

I compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=2.85cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.85cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
￼\pgfplotsset{tick label style={
    font=\scriptsize}} %  this modifies the ‘every tick label’ style
\begin{axis}[title={Curva de calentamiento de una sustancia},
    xlabel={{\scriptsize Tiempo de calentamiento (min.)}},
    ylabel={{\scriptsize Temperatura}},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=-50, ymax=160,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={-40,-20,0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
       xmajorgrids=true,
        xminorgrids=true,
         yminorgrids=true,
    grid style=dotted,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,-30)(10,0)(30,0)(60,80)(80,80)(100,140)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This code does not work fine. Only if I erase the line    `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

How can I resolve the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is an odd character before `\pgfplotsset`:

```
￼\pgfplotsset{tick label style={
```

In the posting it is the Unicode replacement character, but it could be something else in the source code (a candidate would be the unbreakable space character, sometimes inserted by editors).

After removing it, the example would probably run fine. Otherwise check the reported line of the error message and inspect the file at this line in a hex editor for unusual stuff.